# MULE domain project classloader error

Tags: java, mule, classloader

I have a domain project which has http listener in it . and i have a mule app which references this domain project http listener .

Mule domain project does not have any jar files in its lib folder .

My mule app has lib folder with different jar files .

Now jar files of my mule app is loaded by MuleSharedDomainClassLoader , and because of that , certain classloading of my mule app fails with ClassNotFoundException , because it searches the class only in mule domain lib folder . 
how to resolve this

Comment: Are you saying that your Mule application can't access classes in any of the JARs in its `/lib` directory? If yes, you're going to have to provide way more details to track the issue because it should work.

Comment: Ok it was my mistake , mule domain project contained the lib folder , that is why these jars are loaded by the domain classloader , after removing lib folder , it get loaded correctly by app classloader and problem resolved , thanks for reply @DavidDossot